# optimization Determine the coordinates of point

Tags: calculus, optimization

Determine the coordinates of point P of the line passing through points (a; 0) and (0; b), where
a and b are positive, which maximize the area of ​​the rectangle shown in the diagram.

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfK9q.png)

if someone can give me some explanation it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem in many different ways.

The equation of the straight line is $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} = 1$

Let the co-ordinates of $P$ be $(t, b(1-\frac{t}{a}))$

Area of the rectangle $f(t) = bt(1-\frac{t}{a})$

You need to find the value of $t$ that maximizes $f(t)$

**Method 1: Algebra**

Since $f(t) = \frac{b}{a} \left(\frac{a^2}{4} - (t-\frac{a}{2})^2 \right)$

it is maximum when $t = \frac{a}{2}$, i.e., the co-ordinates of $P$ are $(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{b}{2})$

**Method 2: Calculus**

Set $f'(t) = 0 \implies t = \frac{a}{2}$ and $f''(t) < 0$ means this is indeed a maxima

**Method 3: Lagrange multiplier**

Let the co-ordinates of $P$ be $(x, y)$

Consider $L = xy + \lambda (\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} - 1)$

Set $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = 0$ and solve to obtain $x = \frac{a}{2}$ and $y = \frac{b}{2}$